# What method in the String class returns only the first N characters?

Tags: c#, .net, string, character

I'd like to write an extension method to the `String` class so that if the input string to is longer than the provided length `N`, only the first `N` characters are to be displayed.

Here's how it looks like:

```
public static string TruncateLongString(this string str, int maxLength)
{
    if (str.Length <= maxLength)
        return str;
    else
        //return the first maxLength characters                
}
```

What `String.*()` method can I use to get only the first `N` characters of `str`?

Answer (score 474, accepted):

```
public static string TruncateLongString(this string str, int maxLength)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return str;

    return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(str.Length, maxLength));
}
```

In C# 8 or later it is also possible to use a [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) to make this a bit terser:

```
public static string TruncateLongString(this string str, int maxLength)
{
    return str?[0..Math.Min(str.Length, maxLength)];
}
```

Which can be further reduced using an expression body:

```
public static string TruncateLongString(this string str, int maxLength) =>
    str?[0..Math.Min(str.Length, maxLength)];
```

Note null-conditional operator (`?`) is there to handle the case where `str` is null. This replaces the need for an explict null check.

Comment: Is the Math.Min needed?  I thought Substring knew that if the second parameter was greater than the length, it just plugged in the length?

Comment: I believe it is: System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks would throw ArgumentOutOfRange.

Comment: @Martin: not that I can see, `startIndex > (this.Length - length)` throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: I was going to suggest checking if `Math.Min(str.Length, maxLength) == str.Length` in case you end up creating an unnecessary string to return "the first str.Length characters of str", but Substring does that check for you and just does `return this` if you've asked for the whole string.

Comment: If you want the extension method to work on potentially null strings... return str?.Substring(0, Math.Min(str.Length, maxLength));

Answer (score 85):

```
string truncatedToNLength = new string(s.Take(n).ToArray());
```

This solution has a tiny bonus in that if n is greater than s.Length, it still does the right thing.

Comment: Yeah, but using Linq to truncate a string? Just be aware this will perform very badly if used many times such as in a loop. Don't do this as a matter of habit

Comment: @ErikE it might be noted that this is fine solution for one-time short string processing.

Comment: I agree, readability is usually more important than micro perf. When perf becomes an issue, then can reassess. The majority of the time it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MattGreer Using Linq for substringing when the perfectly clear `String.Substring` method already exists is precisely the kind of coding that junior developers think is clever but ticks off their seniors.The deeper meaning of "avoid premature optimization" as intended by the coiner of that phrase would actually suggest avoiding this answer. String handling is one of the MOST ripe areas for performance destruction in all of computing, and caring nothing about performance in favor of "waiting until there's an issue" is far inferior to mindfully writing code unlikely to have performance issues.

Comment: Here is the benchmark: https://gist.github.com/ultimaweapon/15d52c412612fedd2812068952006122

Comment: @ErikE: It's not the `String.Substring` that is unclear, but the fact that you require a `Math.Min` or a similar construction to check the number of characters to take with the total string length. `str.Substring(0, 5)` - very clear indeed. But `str.Substring(0, Math.Min(str.Length, 5))` - no, that's not really the same level of 'clear'. It's obvious what it does, but it is not the "at a glance"-clarity you'd get from `str.Substring(0, 5)` - or from `str.Take(5)`, for that matter.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I mean, I agree it's super annoying to make taking more than the length of a string an error.

Comment: @ErikE: Exactly, as the requirement "take the first N characters" almost always means "take up to N characters, or less if the string is not that long". Combine that with a tendency not to write the same self-baked general boilerplate code over and over and stick to framework functions (which is actually good practice in many cases, even though not so much in this particular case), it's not surprising to frequently encounter the fallback to LINQ's `.Take(...)` extension method.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper for one-offs I guess I agree, but getting in TOO fluid a habit of using it just isn't helpful long-term. I'd rather code up a quick extension method and use that.

Comment: @ErikE: Writing a custom extension method for that purpose is trivial, of course, but then, that often leads to the following dilemma IMHO: I need exactly this extension method in virtually every project. Do I copy and paste the code? That feels fundamentally wrong, even for small portions. Do I put it into a reusable assembly? Sounds like overkill, and also like overhead for the runtime. What do I do across organisations - do I use the same code block for different employers and my spare-time pet projects? That must be a recipe for getting myself into trouble :/

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I hear what you're saying.

Answer (score 33):

Whenever I have to do string manipulations in C#, I miss the good old `Left` and `Right` functions from Visual Basic, which are much simpler to use than `Substring`.

So in most of my C# projects, I create extension methods for them:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Left(this string str, int length)
    {
        return str.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, str.Length));
    }

    public static string Right(this string str, int length)
    {
        return str.Substring(str.Length - Math.Min(length, str.Length));
    }
}
```

*Note:

The `Math.Min` part is there because `Substring` throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when the input string's length is smaller than the requested length, as already mentioned in some comments under previous answers.*

### Usage:

```
string longString = "Long String";

// returns "Long";
string left1 = longString.Left(4);

// returns "Long String";
string left2 = longString.Left(100);
```

Comment: I like this, but if the string was shorter than given length, it would not append spaces.  `public static string Left(this string str, int length) { var Result = str.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, str.Length)); return (Result.Length < length) ? Result.PadRight(length) : Result; }`

Comment: `str` needs to be checked for null

Answer (score 31):

You can use LINQ `str.Take(n)` or `str.SubString(0, n)`, where the latter will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception for `n > str.Length`.

Mind that the LINQ version returns a `IEnumerable<char>`, so you'd have to convert the `IEnumerable<char>` to `string`: `new string(s.Take(n).ToArray())`.

Comment: Don't use Linq to truncate strings. That's ridiculous.

Answer (score 17):

Simply:

```
public static String Truncate(String input,int maxLength)
{
   if(input.Length > maxLength)
      return input.Substring(0,maxLength);
   return input;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
public static string TruncateLongString(this string str, int maxLength)
{
    return str.Length <= maxLength ? str : str.Remove(maxLength);
}
```

Comment: Also, note that you could also make the extension method null-safe by changing the condition to `str == null || str.Length <= maxLength`

Comment: For anyone wondering whether `Remove` or `Substring` is better, there's no difference. `Remove(maxLength)` just calls `Substring(0,maxLength)` after a bit of bounds checking. Which you prefer depends on whether you think of the truncation as "take the first maxLength characters" or "throw away everything after maxLength characters". Of course, it's really both so it's up to you.

Answer (score 5):

if we are talking about validations also why we have not checked for null string entries. Any specific reasons?

I think below way help since IsNullOrEmpty is a system defined method and ternary operators have cyclomatic complexity = 1 while if() {} else {} has value 2.

```
    public static string Truncate(string input, int truncLength)
    {
        return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && input.Length >= truncLength)
                   ? input.Substring(0, truncLength)
                   : input;
    }
```

Comment: what is an issue with cyclomatic complexity 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

With the [C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)

```
public static string TruncateLongString(this string str, int maxLength)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return str;

    return str[.. Math.Min(str.Length, maxLength)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added this in my project just because where I'm using it is a high chance of it being used in loops, in a project hosted online hence I didn't want any crashes if I could manage it. The length fits a column I have. It's C#7

Just a one line:

```
 public static string SubStringN(this string Message, int Len = 499) => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Message) ? (Message.Length >= Len ? Message.Substring(0, Len) : Message) : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Substring method is fraught with peril. I developed extension methods that handle a wide variety of scenarios. The nice thing is it preserves the original behavior, but when you add an additional "true" parameter, it then resorts to the extension method to handle the exception, and returns the most logical values, based on the index and length. For example, if length is negative, and counts backward. You can look at the test results with wide variety of values on the fiddle at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m1mSH9. This will give you a clear idea on how it resolves substrings.

I always add these methods to all my projects, and never have to worry about code breaking, because something changed and the index is invalid. Below is the code.

```
    public static String Substring(this String val, int startIndex, bool handleIndexException)
    {
        if (!handleIndexException)
        { //handleIndexException is false so call the base method
            return val.Substring(startIndex);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
        {
            return val;
        }
        return val.Substring(startIndex < 0 ? 0 : startIndex > (val.Length - 1) ? val.Length : startIndex);
    }

    public static String Substring(this String val, int startIndex, int length, bool handleIndexException)
    {
        if (!handleIndexException)
        { //handleIndexException is false so call the base method
            return val.Substring(startIndex, length);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
        {
            return val;
        }
        int newfrom, newlth, instrlength = val.Length;
        if (length < 0) //length is negative
        {
            newfrom = startIndex + length;
            newlth = -1 * length;
        }
        else //length is positive
        {
            newfrom = startIndex;
            newlth = length;
        }
        if (newfrom + newlth < 0 || newfrom > instrlength - 1)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        if (newfrom < 0)
        {
            newlth = newfrom + newlth;
            newfrom = 0;
        }
        return val.Substring(newfrom, Math.Min(newlth, instrlength - newfrom));
    }
```

I blogged about this back in May 2010 at: http://jagdale.blogspot.com/2010/05/substring-extension-method-that-does.html

Answer (score 0):

Partially for the sake of summarization (excluding LINQ solution), here's two one-liners that address the `int maxLength` caveat of allowing negative values and also the case of null string:

1. The `Substring` way (from [Paul Ruane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3566842/2603874)):

```
public static string Truncate(this string s, uint maxLength) =>
    s?.Substring(0, Math.Min(s.Length, (int)maxLength));
```

2. The `Remove` way (from [kbrimington's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3566862/2603874)):

```
public static string Truncate(this string s, uint maxLength) =>
    s?.Length > maxLength ? s.Remove((int)maxLength) : s;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string text = "1234567";
var x = text.Substring(0, text.Length>5?6:text.Length);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
substring(int startpos, int lenght);
```

Answer (score -4):

string.Substring(0,n); // 0 - start index and n - number of characters

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer, this can result in index out of bounds errors.