# Cut off the end of a string

Tags: c#, string, trim

I need to figure out how to remove the end of a string. The only trouble is, the string itself is not set. All I want to keep is the first 3-4 characters in the string.

```
string Location = "110 - Main Road";
string Location = "123 - Highway";
string Location = "234 - My House";
```

It could also be;

```
string Location = "1120 - Main Road";
```

I know if I can cut it down to the first 4 characters, I can just use `.Trim()` to remove the white spaces if it is only 3 characters, but I don't know how to cut it down to the first 4 characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What method in the String class returns only the first N characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566830/what-method-in-the-string-class-returns-only-the-first-n-characters)

Comment: Are you just trying to grab the number at the beginning? Basically the number before the first space?

Comment: @NeilN yes that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Split` and get your number like this:

```
string Location = "1120 - Main Road";
int number = int.Parse(Location.Split()[0]);
```

This should work if there is no white-space before the number.If there is then use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
int number = int.Parse(Location.Split(new []{ ' ' }, 
              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
```

Comment: does this also work if I want to grab the second half of the string also? eg. `int number = 1120; string location = 'Main Road'`?

Comment: @Ben if you want to get second half use: `Location.Split('-')[1].Trim();`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function to split your string based on delimeter `-` and then you can convert the first part of the string into integer if you want it in a Integer variable.

**Solution 1:** if you want to get first part of string as as string.

```
string Location = "11056 - Main Road";
Location = Location.Split('-')[0].Trim();
```

**Solution 2:**  if you want to get the first part of the string as integer value.

```
string Location = "11056 - Main Road";
int num;
int.TryParse(Location.Split('-')[0],out num);
```

Answer (score 2):

split on spaces, then grab whatever is first, ignore the rest.

```
string GrabNumber(string input)
{
    return input.Split(' ')[0];
}
```

assuming you want it as an integer you can take it a step further:

```
int GrabNumber(string input)
{
    return int.Parse(input.Split(' ')[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call with a [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        List<string> strings  = new List<string>();
        strings.Add("110 - Main Road");
        strings.Add("1104 - Main Road");
        strings.Add("11088 - Main Road");

        foreach(string s in strings){
            Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf("-",0)-1));

        }
    }
}
```

That way even if the street number is 4,5,6,7 characters long this will still work

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first 4 characters you would do this:

```
Location = Location.Substring(0, 4);
```

The first argument is the start position and the second argument is the length.

Comment: The 2nd param is length, so it should be 4

Answer (score 0):

use the substring function of string(startIndex,numberOfCharToKeep) like this:

```
string Location = "110 - Main Road";
string NewLocation = Location.SubString(0,4);
```

this keeps your first 4 chars

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how reliable your input is. If you will always have a space after the numbers you can find that location using IndexOf. However, whenever I work with strings I prefer regular expressions. Here is an example of both approaches:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] locations = 
        { 
            "110 - Main Road", 
            "123 - Highway", 
            "234 - My House", 
            "1120 - Main Road" 
        };

        Regex r = new Regex(@"^\d+");

        foreach (string location in locations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(location.Substring(0, location.IndexOf(' ')));
            Console.WriteLine(r.Match(location).Captures[0].Value);
        }
    }
}
```